# Do goclipse goarch settings matter?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, go, goclipse

I downloaded and installed the go1.1.2.windows-amd64.msi from the [Go distribution page](http://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list) and set it up on eclipse with the goclipse plugin.

The baffling thing is that in the goclipse settings, the **GOARCH** settings don't seem to matter. I can start a new project with the GOARCH settings set to *arm*, *386* or *amd64* and the project will still compile and run just fine.

Is there a setting i'm supposed to conform to or does the GOARCH setting not matter at all?

Additionally, are the Go distributions with the suffix amd64 supposed to be for 64bit AMD chips and not intel ones? (the naming convention was a little confusing)

My Current Setup:

Eclipse Keplar 64bit

Goclipse 0.7.6

go version go1.1.2 windows/amd64
running on windows 7 64-bit on a Intel i7-3630QM

Comment: There seems to be an [open bug](http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/issues/detail?id=99) relating to this not working.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about goclipse, but as to suffix on windows

GOARCH=386 will generate 32 bit OS exe
and
GOARCH=amd64 will make 64 bit exe.

Go generated programs will run on any modern CPU that your Windows runs (excluding ARM).

Alex